# C# handle force closed socket connection

Tags: c#, sockets, exception

Let's say my client application looses connection with server application because of internet problems, the Server then receives a "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" exception.

What's the proper way to catch this exception, close the server-side socket and then remove it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The proper response to this error is to catch the exception, close the socket, and remove it from any of your application's data structures. Which is what you said.

Answer (score 1):

this largely depends on what class you're using to establish and maintain the connection.

I typically use TcpClient, TcpListener and their asynchronous functions. When error occurs, the callback function is called with e.Error != null. What usually follows is the removal of the socket, which is conveniently available in e.UserState, from the list of active connections.